# Does empty feasible direction implies global minimum?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider minimizing a function $f$ over the constraint set $C$. Now, if $x \in C$ with no feasible directions then x is a global minimum.

My attempt:
If from point $x$ there is no feasible direction then that implies that entire set $C$ is actually a singleton set. Hence, $x$ has to be the global minimum since it is the only point in the feasible set.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: What if $C$ is discrete?

Comment: The function is continuous. Can you give an example of the case?

Comment: Can you provide more context? If $C$ is discrete or ar singleton, why talk about feasible directions?

Comment: $C$ is continuous. By singleton, I mean that it consist of only one single feasible point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x has to be the global minimum since it is the only point in the feasible set.